# Xcode Frameworks Breaking in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, frameworks, swift3

I am creating, exporting, importing, and using frameworks in Swift 3.0. Creation, exportation, and importation is working, but I get an error when I try to use any of the classes in the framework. Here is *where* I get the error:

```
let myTestFramework = TestFramework()
```

And here *is* the error:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<TestFramework>'
```

[Here](https://ony.io/r1mI) is a link to the tutorial I am using (with module name "`TestFramework`"). How do I fix this error?

Comment: It might help people answer your question if you provided a brief snippet of the code where you get the error

Comment: @OmniProg I updated my post to provide a link to a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Please just ensure that MotionKit is fully installed on the device. Use Xcode CLI tools to ensure that your simulator is including the MotionKit and associated hardware components.

Remember, MotionKit **requires** that you have an accelerometer in use and active within the device. Xcode's iPad and iPhone 4-7 simulators **do not ship with the hardware components required** and so you'll need to connect them yourself here... [Apple - MotionKit installation guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M7WBQAX)

Comment: Go look at the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out your issue with more detail. I'm experiencing a similar issue. Here's what I was able to do to fix it: (I recommend carefully following all steps in order)

1. Use Xcode CLI tools to install related hardware and software components.
2. See [Apple's MotionKit usage and troubleshooting guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M7WBQAX) as it has a direct solution to this issue.
3. As the troubleshooting guide suggests, you should properly install the related hardware components required to allow Xcode to function with iPad Pro MotionKit simulator.

Comment: I'm not using Apple MotionKit... I created my own framework called MotionKit.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so to properly utilize Apple's MotionKit framework, you MUST install the related hardware components! See my previously stated instructions for more detail. Do **not override the default MotionKit** library provided by Apple!

You must use Apple's MotionKit library, do not name your custom library "MotionKit"!

Related hardware components for MotionKit in iPad Pro simulator can be found on the [Apple hardware components support page for Xcode](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0043H2KAY).

Comment: @Bennett No, do not change the name now! Apple will deny it from entering the App Store if you do. Have you looked over the hardware documentation I've linked in this answer?

Comment: I'm simply doing a test with creating and using a module... I never wanted to use Apple MotionKit or put this on the App Store..

Comment: @Bennett But you're trying to upload this software to the App Store, correct? For iPad Pro devices and newer, such as iOS Siri with gyroscope?

Comment: @Bennett Apologies, my link copy and paster on my keyboard is broken. Here's the correct Apple docs link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht205025

Comment: Um, that's how to fix your Apple Watch

Comment: @Bennett I think you're mistaken, good sir. I don't own an Apple Watch! Has the issue been solved? If so, would you mind marking this answer as correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just noticed a problem in my code. I'll update it in a few hours.